# Making placeholders in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, razor, iteration

I need to make "placeholders" where a foreach loop iterations does not fill out a row in a grid system.

There is room for 3 columns per row.
If there is only 1 iterations in the loop, make 2 empty column with eg. a background image.

If there is only 2 iterations in the loop, make 1 empty column with eg. a background image.

If there is 3, 6, 9, 12 etc. per row, make no placeholders.

I'm looking for a more dynamic way to make these logics (and more clean code).

```
var loop = GetLoop("ItemPublisher:Items.List");
int totalItems = loop.Count;

int remainders = totalItems % 3;
int placeholders = 3 - remainders;
string renderPlaceholders = placeholders == 3 ? "0" : placeholders.ToString();
int index = 0;

@foreach(var i in loop){
    var title = i.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Title");
    var imagepath = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Image.ImagePath")) ? i.GetString("ItemPublisher:Item.Image.ImagePath") : "/Files/Images/placeholder.jpg";
    <div class="grid__col-md-4">
            <h4>@title</h4>
            <img src="/Admin/Public/GetImage.ashx?width=992&height=560&crop=0&Compression=75&image=@imagepath"/>
    </div>
}

@*Render placeholders*@  
@if(placeholders == 1)
{
    var imagepath = "/Files/Images/placeholder.jpg";
    <div class="grid__col-md-4 placeholder">
        <h4></h4>
        <img src="/Admin/Public/GetImage.ashx?width=992&height=560&crop=0&Compression=75&image=@imagepath"/>
    </div>
}
else if(placeholders == 2)
{
    var imagepath = "/Files/Images/placeholder.jpg";
    <div class="grid__col-md-4 placeholder">
        <h4></h4>
        <img src="/Admin/Public/GetImage.ashx?width=992&height=560&crop=0&Compression=75&image=@imagepath"/>
    </div>

    <div class="grid__col-md-4 placeholder">
        <h4></h4>
        <img src="/Admin/Public/GetImage.ashx?width=992&height=560&crop=0&Compression=75&image=@imagepath"/>
    </div>

  }
```